# Convergence of $f(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{T-t}} dy$ when $t\rightarrow T$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

We look at the real function $f(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{T-t}} dy$ on the domain $[0,T) \times \mathbb R$. What happens when $t\rightarrow T$ ?

Denoting the limit $f(T,x)$, I feel like $f(T,x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ as $e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{T-t}} \rightarrow 0$ unless $x=y$, which is of Lebesgue measure $0$, so it does not matter in the integral. But the author of the article I am reading says $f(T,x)= 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Is there a $1/\sqrt{T}$ factor that you are missing?

Comment: The closed form of the integral is $\sqrt{(T-t)\pi}$, which approaches $0$ as $t \to T$.